# How to get a hostname that contains a certain string from a group in Ansible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm using Ansible and need to lookup my database server to use in a config file.

I have a group of all database servers: `groups.rds` and I know that the server I'm looking for contains a certain string, eg. "development".

What is the cleanest way to find that hostname?

I'm looking for something like this: `groups.rds.contains("development").first()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [`select` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select), combined with the [`match` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters).

```
groups.rds | select("match", ".*production.*") | first
```

But you're asking for the cleanest solution. From here it looks like you're trying to identify an environment (development) based on a host name. If that's the case, wouldn't it make sense to have another group for this?

If you'd had something like this:

```
[non_rds]
some.unrelated.development.host

[rds]
some.production.host
some.staging.host
some.development.host

[production]
some.production.host

[staging]
some.staging.host

[development]
some.development.host
some.unrelated.development.host
```

Then it would be very easy to get the intersection of these groups:

```
groups.rds | intersect(groups.development) | first
```

This would give you only the hosts which are in both groups `rds` and `development`, which is `some.development.host`.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: How would I assign the output of that to a variable? `database_host: "{{ groups.rds | intersect(groups.tag_Env_development) | first | default('localhost') }}"` does not seem to work unless I use it in a template.

Comment: Are you doing this in a group- or host-vars file? Or in a vars file of a role?

Comment: In /vars/main.yml and including it in my playbook like this `vars_files:
    - vars/main.yml`

Comment: I see... It might be the vars files are imported into the playbook before the inventory is created. Would a `set_fact` task solve this for you?